# Mail header to answer to a email with php

Tags: php, email, email-headers

My goal is to anwer to a mail to a email that is in a inbox of a mailbox.
I am at the point that I can read the mail out of the mailbox and I can send emails.

The only thing is that I would like it for the receiver of the email that all the conversations are wrapped in 1 email. You know with gmail you see for example a subject like this:

```
(5) Test subject
```

This means that this mails contains 5 submails.

But at this point everytime I send a answer to the existing email with php it comes in as a completely new mail. And it does not stack on top of eachother.

Does anyone know how to make these emails stack on eachother.

My current code for sending the mail:

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: reply@reply.nl \r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= "From: sender@sender.nl\r\n";

mail("test@test.nl", "test subject", "test message", $headers);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to include the `In-Reply-To` and the `References` Header.

In `In-Reply-To` is the `Message-ID`-Header you are directly refering too and `References` are commaseperated values of all messages (e.g. when you reply back and forth, then it would make sense to include all of the message IDs)

Example:

```
In-Reply-To: <GDKDHK@web.de>
References: <a1gjkr@googlemail.com>,<GDKDHK@web.de>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to RE: subject so that they can stack in the email viewer.